# Leaflet current position multiple markers

Tags: leaflet

Hello everyone I have some problems its about the current positionmarker in my leaflet its supposed to update every 3 second and it does but it everytime it puts a new "position" marker on the map and the old one stays how can i fix this?

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
attribution: '© Leaflet 2021',
tileSize: 512,
zoomOffset: -1,
id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
accessToken: '######'
}).addTo(map);

    var greenIcon = L.icon({

    iconUrl: 'person.png',


    iconSize:     [35, 35], // size of the icon  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [0, -20] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    });
    // placeholders for the L.marker and L.circle representing user's current position and accuracy
    var current_position, current_accuracy;




    function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
        var marker;

                
        L.marker(e.latlng, {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map)


    }




    // wrap map.locate in a function
    function locate() {
      map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 15});
    }



            map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

    // call locate every 3 seconds... forever
    setInterval(locate, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient way to fix this is to keep a reference to the marker you create, so that you can update its position rather than creating a new marker each time you get a location update.  The reference needs to be held in a variable that is outside your callback function, but in scope when the callback is created.

For instance, your callback can check whether the marker already exists, and either create it and attach it to the `map` object for easy re-use, or just update its coordinates if it is already there:

```
function onLocationFound(e) {
    var radius = e.accuracy / 2;
    
    if (map._here_marker) {
        // Update the marker if it already exists.
        map._here_marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
    } else {
        // Create a new marker and add it to the map
        map._here_marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
    }
}
```

Having this reference will also let you edit the marker from other functions, e.g. to change the icon or popup, hide it from view, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, for example, in the following way.
Add an ID (customId) to the marker:

```js
const marker = L.marker([lng, lat], {
  id: customId
});
```

And when you add a new marker remove the existing one with the code below:

```js
map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  if (layer.options && layer.options.pane === "markerPane") {
    if (layer.options.id !== customId) {
      map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This could work, but could be quite inefficient in applications where lots of other layers are displayed on the map. I think there is also a typo: the `!--` should be a `===` to avoid deleting every marker except the one you want.  If you keep a reference to the marker, you can remove it from the map directly with `marker.remove()`, but it would be more efficient just to reposition it, and avoid creating lots of new markers.